# PHP session variable undefined

Tags: php, session-variables

I have this session variable which i am trying to set to an access level when the users logs in with this:

```
 $accessquery = mysql_query("SELECT roleid FROM person WHERE email = '". $email ."'");
 $access = mysql_fetch_array($accessquery);

 $_SESSION['Access'] = $access;
```

However it says that 'Access' is undefined, what is the problem?

EDIT*

```
if (($_SESSION['Access']) == "2")
```

Error appears here

EDIT*

Session Start has been called.

Comment: Where does it say that? Did you remember to start the session?

Comment: Post the code where you have the error.

Comment: I don't see where the access is being defined nor do I see `session_start();`

Comment: You should really watch out for SQL injections with code like this. If this were production code, your site would be hacked within 2 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities here :

1. Start the session by using `session_start();` at the begining of page.
2. use the following code:

   ```
   $accessquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT roleid FROM person WHERE email = '". $email ."'", mysqli_store_result($conn));

   $access = mysqli_fetch_row($accessquery);

   $_SESSION['Access'] = $access[0];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what's going on, I recommend you to use

```
print_r($any_variable);
```

See http://php.net/print_r

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `session_start();`?

Try to debug your code with just a fixed value: `$_SESSION["Test"]="test";` and then do a `var_dump($_SESSION);`